# Errors while creating stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Below errors appear when i am trying to create simple stored procedure in SQL Server

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 2 Incorrect syntax
>   near 'varchar'. Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 27
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@".

Very much new to writing stored procedures. Kindly guide

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
    @[CUSTNAME] VARCHAR(100),                   
    @[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME] VARCHAR(25),
    @[COUNTRY] VARCHAR(50),
    @[region] VARCHAR(25),
    @[Area] VARCHAR(25),
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[TEST]
    SET
          @[CUSTNAME]=[CUSTNAME]
        , @[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME]=[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME]
        , @[COUNTRY]=[COUNTRY]
        , @[region]=[region]
        , @[Area]=[Area]
    WHERE period=@period
        AND customer=@customer

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to get rid of `[]` in your variables. And also your update query is wrong:

```
USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]

   @CUSTNAME VARCHAR(100),                   
   @CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME VARCHAR(25),
   @COUNTRY VARCHAR(50),
   @region VARCHAR(25),
   @Area VARCHAR(25),

AS BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE [dbo].[TEST]
   SET
          [CUSTNAME] = @CUSTNAME
        , [CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME] = @CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME
        , [COUNTRY] = @COUNTRY
        , [region] = @region
        , [Area] = @Area
  WHERE period = @period
    AND customer = @customer

END
```

And you also need to add parameters for `@period` and `@customer`.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [my_db]

    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   create PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]

   @CUSTNAME varchar(100),                   
   @CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME varchar(25),
   @COUNTRY varchar(50),
   @region varchar(25),
   @Area varchar(25),
   @period varchar(50),
   @customer varchar(50)
   AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   update [dbo].[TEST]
   set @CUSTNAME=[CUSTNAME]
  ,@CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME=[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME]
  ,@COUNTRY=[COUNTRY]
  ,@region=[region]
  ,@Area=[Area]
  where period=@period
  and customer=@customer
  END
GO
```

Remove []  For 1st Error,
Add 2 parameter @Period and @customer

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values in opposite way.

**Error lies here**

> `update [dbo].[TEST] set @[CUSTNAME]=[CUSTNAME] > ,@[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME]=[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME] ,@[COUNTRY]=[COUNTRY] > ,@[region]=[region] ,@[Area]=[Area] where period=@period and > customer=@customer END`

***Try this instead of above code***

```
 update [dbo].[TEST]
   set [CUSTNAME]=@CUSTNAME
  ,[CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME]=@CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME
  ,[COUNTRY]=@COUNTRY
  ,[region]=@region
  ,[Area]=@Area
  where period=@period
  and customer=@customer
  END
```